# Rails app redirects root request to /404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I can't figure out why my application isn't working properly.

I've got the following `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'visitors#index'

  # ... other routes

  # Default root
  get '*path', to: "error#error_404"

end
```

I enter the `http://localhost:3000` in the browser url and get redirected to `http://localhost:3000/404`. Logs tell me one thing:

```
Started GET "/404" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-31 14:24:50 +0300
Processing by ErrorController#error_404 as HTML
  Parameters: {"path"=>"404"}
  Rendered error/error_404.html.slim within layouts/application (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.slim (2.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.slim (3.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.slim (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.slim (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 876ms (Views: 875.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Other related files are the following:

**visitors_controller.rb**

```
class VisitorsController < ApplicationController

    def index       
        @specializations = Specialization.order(name: :asc)
    end
...
```

**views/visitors/index.html.slim**

```
- if @specializations.count == 0 
  h3.bg-primary.text-center = I18n.t('layout.no_specializations')

- @specializations.each_with_index do |specialization, index|
  - if index % 3 == 0
    .row
  .col-sm-4
    = link_to specialization
      img src="#{specialization.avatar.url(:thumb)}" /
      p.text-center
        = specialization.name
  - if index % 3 == 2
```

What can be the issue here?

P.S. When I enter e,g, `localhost:3000/specializations/1` the resulting page gets normally loaded.

**UPDATE**

`curl localhost:3000` gets the right HTML, without any redirection.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be bad slim code. This line:

`img src="#{specialization.avatar.url(:thumb)}" /`

should be refactored into

`img src=specialization.avatar.url(:thumb) /`

Done. works.